# How to check and validate user input is one of two valid choices

Tags: c, validation, char, user-input

I have the following code asking for user input either A or P. I have the same sort of setup for hour and minutes, where hour would be between 1 and 12 and minutes would be between 0 and 59. That part of my code is thoroughly working.

My issue is that I don't know how to check what the timePeriod variable is and ensure that it is either A or P and to print an error message and prompt again if it is anything else including lowercase a and p. User input has to be in uppercase and ONLY A or P.

I've only put the function code here. I added the clean_stdin code as well so the while statement inside getTimePeriod might be easier to understand. As I said before, I'm using a similar set up for both the hour and minutes and that's working.

```
char getTimePeriod(void)
{
    char timePeriod, term;

    while ( (((scanf("%c%c",&timePeriod,&term)!=2 || term !='\n') && clean_stdin()) || timePeriod != "A" || timePeriod != "P") && printf("Invalid value entered. Must be A or P. Please re-enter: ") );

    return timePeriod;
}


int clean_stdin()
{
    while (getchar()!='\n');
    return 1; 
}
```

**Edit:** For those getting their panties in a twist about this being bad code, it works for me based on my assignment requirements for an **Intro to C** course. Hope that clarifies the noob-ness of this question as well.

Also note that

```
timePeriod != 'A'
```

does not work. I don't know why but it doesn't work.

Comment: Another example of bad coding style.

Comment: `timePeriod != "A"`. That's invalid code. `"A"` is a string whereas `timePeriod` is a single `char` (and you can't do string comparisons like that in C anyway). You want `timePeriod != 'A'`. And suggest you dial down the cuteness and not try to put everything inside the `while` condition. It'll make your code much easier to maintain.

Comment: As a usability suggestion, you should allow and ignore leading white space (it's easy; use `" %c%c"` to skip them).  I'd suggest allowing trailing white space too; that's harder.  I'd probably use line-based input (e.g. POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), or `fgets()` if that isn't available) and then `sscanf()` to do the checking — with some consequential alterations to the input.  This avoids skipping lots of newlines with no extra prompt, which the leading blank in the format would otherwise permit.

Comment: Requiring case-sensitivity also seems unnnecessarily harsh; what damage is there from accepting `'a'` or `'p'` instead?  Also, having to type the AM or PM indicator on a line on its own seems…unpleasant?  Does that mean that the user can't type 12:59 PM?  Is there actually a problem with the user typing PM or AM?  Be wary of being too strict; it makes it harder to use the resulting program.

Comment: @Olaf if you have nothing useful to say, why bother commenting?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for actually adding some useful (albeit complicated) things in your comment and asking question instead of just blasting at me. This is part of an assignment for an Intro to C course that I'm taking. The harsh (and quite unnecessary) requirements are that of my teacher. If I want the marks, I have to stick to those.

Comment: Ridiculous constraints are often the results of course requirements; that's a common issue here on SO.  Pointing out that they are not sensible for (what passes as) the 'real world' may help you get or keep perspective.  One reason that teacher apply the constraints is that they often make the code simpler to write, at the expense of usability.  There's time enough to worry about usability later — you need the fundamentals first.  But just keep in mind that users are more important than teachers in the long run (but not in the short term).

Comment: @AlanAu I've tried the `'A'` and that's not working at all. As for your cuteness comment, its not trying to be 'cute' (wtf does that even mean?), its the one way it works for me based on the requirements. If you have a better suggestion or better yet since you think you're a know-it-all, just do my assignment for me. That 'cute' enough for you?

Comment: I think making clear that this is bad coding style is very useful for newbies who might feel tempted to take this for serious. If you had read that much bad code from people who insist they learned it that way, you might agree. Unless you are one of those people being proud no one - including themselves two weeks later - can read the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is here:

```
timePeriod != "A" || timePeriod != "P"
```

First, as was mentioned before, you can't compare a character to a string.  You need to use single quotes instead of double quotes.  Assuming that's been corrected, this conditional will always be true since `timePeriod` will always either not be `'A'` or not be `'P'`.  This needs to be a logical AND:

```
(timePeriod != 'A' && timePeriod != 'P')
```

Note also that an extra set of parenthesis were added to make sure that the order of operation in your `while` expression is preserved.

Regarding the "cute" comment, what that means is that cramming a bunch of statements in the `while` expression and leaving the body blank makes your code difficult to read and therefore more prone to bugs.  Had you broken that up into multiple statements each doing one logical thing you would have been more likely to find this bug yourself.  Olaf made the comment he did primarily to warn other users who come across your code about just that.

Comment: Thank you for explaining everything in a civilized manner. It makes a whole lot more sense now. I will change my code to include the `printf` statement in the body instead of keeping it in the expression and make it more readable. The comment Olaf made was primarily useless to me. If he wanted to help, he could've made his comment and added an explanation of what he thought was wrong with the style of the code and how to fix it so it could be better. In that way its very negative and pretty useless to other newbies as well. Just warning wouldn't stop people from using it, esp if it works.

Comment: @nmunchers I'd recommend pulling everything out of the body except for the comparison of `timePeriod`.  It will be a bit more verbose (you may need to add an internal loop around using `scanf` and `getchar`), but more clear what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Recommend separating user input from validation.

`scanf()` tries to do both at once.  It is easier to handle potential wrong user input if simply a line of input is read (`fgets()` - standard or `getline()` common [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)) and then parsed by various means.

```
// return choice or EOF
int GetChoice(const char *prompt, const char *reprompt, const char *choices) {
  char buf[10];
  puts(prompt);
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;  // drop potential trailing \n
    char *p = strchr(choices, buf[0]);
    if (p && buf[1] == '\0') {
      // Could fold upper/lower case here if desired.
      return *p;
    }
    puts(reprompt);
  }
  return EOF;
}

int timePeriod = GetChoice("TimePeriod A or P", "Try Again", "AP");
switch (timePeriod) {
  case 'A' : ...
  case 'P' : ...
  default: ...
```

Additional checks could be added.  That is the best part about rolling this off to a helper function, it can be used is multiple places in code and be improved as needed in a localized manner.

---

OP code comments:
It user input is not as expected, it is unclear that OP's complex  `while()` condition will properly empty user's line of input.  It certainly has trouble if `EOF` is encountered or if first `char` is a `'\n'`.

`timePeriod != "A"` as commented by [@Alan Au](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/alan-au) is not the needed code.  That compares `timePeriod` to the address of the string `"A"`.  Use `timePeriod != 'A'`.

`clean_stdin()` should be `clean_stdin(void)`.  It is an infinite loop on EOF.  Consider:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```